# Android: Basic Database Storage

Tags: java, android, mysql, database, sqlite

I'm new to Android, and databases in general for that matter.

I'm looking for an easy solution to setting up a basic database for my application that will store profiles upon login. What are the benefits of using SQLite (or would it be MySQL?) to set this database up as opposed to internal storage?
Also, If there are any other ways of handling a database of User Profiles likes this that I may be looking for.
For the purposes of this application, since it is essentially "just for fun", I'd ultimately like to go with whatever method is quickest and easiest to implement.

Here is my `Profile` Class:

```
public class Profile{
    private String username;
    private String password;
    private String zip_code;

    public Profile(String username, String password, String zip_code){
        this.username = username;
        this.password = password;
        this.zip_code = zip_code;
    }

    //Followed by getter methods each of the fields
}
```

As an added note, I'll need to be to perform queries of these profiles in my database to ensure that usernames aren't recreated and login credentials (username and password) are valid.

Answer (score 1):

If you're only storing 1 profile, of the person logged in at that time, you could get away with using SharedPreferences.

If you want to store several profiles, a database is the way to go.

On Android it's always a SQLite Database.

To implement a database and its functions, there are 2 main ways of doing it:

1) SQLiteOpenHelper, which includes writing raw SQL commands to access the database. (Many examples of this around the net, just google it)
2) A database ORM library, such as "SugarORM" http://satyan.github.io/sugar/ (There are many different ORMS out there, just google them)

I currently use SugarORM in several different projects, as its very easy to set up, and works very nicely. Absolutely no need for any kind of raw SQL commands, as it handles all of this nicely under the hood, and leaves you with simple functions to use (or, more advanced if you choose to).

Answer (score 0):

It's really a question of scalability, if you are not storing a lot of profiles I would suggest sticking with local storage. SQLite can be useful for storing large amounts of information on a device or caching parts of a larger database, and mysql is really best used as an external database.

Answer (score 0):

It totally depends on the requirement of your application.

you can use `Databases`, `Internal Storage`, `External Storage` **or** `Shared Preferences`.

here you can find the official guide to implementing all these.  https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage#filesExternal